# Service worker Fetch

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm using a Service Worker for working offline. so for Each Fetch request, i store it in the cache.

Now, 
I'd like that the service worker will make a request, and store it as well for next time.
the problem is when i use `fetch(myUrl).then...` , the Fetch Listener `self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e)...`in the service worker doesn't catch it.

I wouldn't like to duplicate code.. any Ideas ?

The fetch listener is:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {

    // e.respondWidth Responds to the fetch event
    e.respondWith(

        // Check in cache for the request being made
        caches.match(e.request)
            .then(function(response) {

                // If the request is in the cache
                if ( response ) {
                    console.log("[ServiceWorker] Found in Cache", e.request.url, response);
                    // Return the cached version
                    return response;
                }

                // If the request is NOT in the cache, fetch and cache

                var requestClone = e.request.clone();
                return fetch(requestClone)
                    .then(function(response) {

                        if ( !response ) {
                            console.log("[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ")
                            return response;
                        }

                        var responseClone = response.clone();

                        //  Open the cache
                        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

                            // Put the fetched response in the cache
                            cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                            console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached', e.request.url);

                            // Return the response
                            return response;

                        }); // end caches.open
                        // returns the fresh response (not cached..)
                        return response;

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err);
                    });


            }) // end caches.match(e.request)
            .catch(function(e){
                // this is - if we still dont have this in the cache !!!
                console.log("[ServiceWorker] ERROR WITH THIS MATCH !!!",e, arguments)
            })// enf of caches.match
    ); // end e.respondWith
});
```

Comment: are you sure your service worker is registered at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since i cant comment to get any specific details and your code seems right to me, my guesses are:

- You Service worker is not registered, or running. you can mak sure It is running by checking the application tab of your inspector. It should look like the following:

[image: running service worker]

- You assume It is not working because of the messages not being logged to the console.
  Service workers run on a different environment from your page, so the messages are logged to a different console that you can check by clicking the inspect button in the image above.

Comment: i do inspect the service worker. For each new request, i write to console. then i run there a function, that is fetching. i get its result in the console, but i dont get the console message from the fetch listener.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the logged messages ?

Answer (score 0):

The Cache then Network strategy is probably what you are looking for:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network

```
var networkDataReceived = false;

startSpinner();

// fetch fresh data
var networkUpdate = fetch('/data.json').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  networkDataReceived = true;
  updatePage();
});

// fetch cached data
caches.match('/data.json').then(function(response) {
  if (!response) throw Error("No data");
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  // don't overwrite newer network data
  if (!networkDataReceived) {
    updatePage(data);
  }
}).catch(function() {
  // we didn't get cached data, the network is our last hope:
  return networkUpdate;
}).catch(showErrorMessage).then(stopSpinner);
```